# Separating Top Nav bar and Side nav bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have TOP nav bar with some menus and Side nav bar with some menus. I given styling for the vertical nav bar , but it reflects to all the nav bar and gives me output like given in picture[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61Rzq.png)

Can anyone suggest me how to seperate the styling for the vertical menu.Vertical menus styling starts from @media

```css
.top-color {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.firstmenu {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-collapse {
    height: auto;
    border-top: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    max-height: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: block !important;
    width: auto !important;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    overflow: visible !important;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.in {
    overflow-x: visible;
  }
  .navbar {
    max-width: 300px;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .navbar-nav,
  .navbar-nav > li,
  .navbar-left,
  .navbar-right,
  .navbar-header {
    float: none !important;
  }
  .navbar-right .dropdown-menu {
    left: 0;
    right: auto;
  }
  .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav.navbar-right:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<title>Bootstrap Case</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar top-color">
    <!--nav header Div-->
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="col-sm-1"><a class="navbar-head" style="text-decoration:none; color:white;" href="#"><h1>My Page</h1></a>
      </div>


    </div>


  </nav>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse firstmenu">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

</body>

</html>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
  </div>

  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

Comment: when there are 2 elements with same class name then we either style them using a unique parent class before these classes or add another unique class or id and style them with those

Comment: actually I named it as verticalmenu and tried styling , but no luck.

Comment: you already have 2 different classes in the navs which are navbar-inverse and navbar-default..so before writing any CSS rules which uses common classes use these in the front like .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.top-color {
      background-color: aquamarine;
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    .firstmenu {
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  display: none ;
}
.navbar.navbar-default {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
.navbar-default .collapse.navbar-collapse.navbar-ex1-collapse {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
      .navbar-collapse {
        height: auto;
        border-top: 0;
        box-shadow: none;
        max-height: none;
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
      }
      .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: block !important;
        width: auto !important;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        overflow: visible !important;
      }
      .navbar-collapse.in {
        overflow-x: visible;
      }
      .navbar {
        max-width: 300px;
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-left: 0;
      }
      .navbar-nav,
      .navbar-nav > li,
      .navbar-left,
      .navbar-right,
      .navbar-header {
        float: none !important;
      }
      .navbar-right .dropdown-menu {
        left: 0;
        right: auto;
      }
      .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav.navbar-right:last-child {
        margin-right: 0;
      }
    }
```

```html
<title>Bootstrap Case</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar top-color">
    <!--nav header Div-->
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="col-sm-1"><a class="navbar-head" style="text-decoration:none; color:white;" href="#"><h1>My Page</h1></a>
      </div>


    </div>


  </nav>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse firstmenu">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

</body>

</html>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
  </div>

  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  

    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

You can try this css:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  display: none ;
}
.navbar.navbar-default {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
.navbar-default .collapse.navbar-collapse.navbar-ex1-collapse {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you , Got an idea now.