# React with Semantic-UI, struggling very hard with how to approach this layout (side bar and top nav bar)

Tags: reactjs, layout, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

My overall goal is something like this for the main overarching layout component:

[image: Valid XHTML]

Live example of my goal: https://app.mobalytics.gg/

Where there is a persistent 'sticky' top bar and side bar at all stages of the application. And then from that point on I use my router to modify the white portion of the screenshot with whatever component / functionality I want the user to experience.

However I am unfortunately struggling to get this to work at all. Various attempts have resulted in navbar overlapping the sidebar and then others the sidebar overlapping the navbar, some attempts crushed the sidebar to basically be only as long as the navbar. Tried using grids and then that crushed the "white portion" when I added components through the router and a few other non-solutions sadly...

How would someone achieve this with semantic-ui-react?

---

Other answers I've looked at and tried to no success sadly:

1: [Separating Top Nav bar and Side nav bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36935299/separating-top-nav-bar-and-side-nav-bar)

2: [Sidebar + Fixed Top Menu in Semantic-UI React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50153383/sidebar-fixed-top-menu-in-semantic-ui-react)

3: [semantic-ui-react fixed sidebar and navbar: can't get sidebar and content to scroll nicely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48290534/semantic-ui-react-fixed-sidebar-and-navbar-cant-get-sidebar-and-content-to-scr)